# If I go into the Item World of an item with no Innocents will Innocents still show up?

Tags: disgaea-5

Besides any specific bonus events like the "Bonus Room" where 6 or 7 Innocents appear at a time.

If you put Innocents into an item and go into the Item world, on random floors those Innocents will show up to be subdued. If there is no Innocent on the item (from either being removed or just never existing) will they continue to show up anyway, just as a random job as opposed to the ones you put there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Innocents won't appear normally if there are no unsubdued innocents on the item.  Bonuses are about the only way you will find innocents from there, or the unique innocents you can get from the item gods.  I haven't had Mr. Egg drop any innocents for me, so there may be other ways to get them to show besides the 1 bonus room.